# Как задать автоматический размер модального окна для элементов position: absolute?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, html, css

Создаю модальное окно на Bootstrap. Вставляю в него элементы `position: absolute`. Как сделать так, чтобы окно автоматически меняло размер?

Comment: @sitev_ru, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Почитайте [про позиционирование](http://htmlbook.ru/css/position) элементов на странице. То, что вы хотите сделать, на чистом css сдать нельзя, но можно попробовать запилить на jquery:

```
var el_width = $(element).width();
$('#popup').css('width', el_width);
```

Но не стоит забывать, что пока элемент невиден (`display: none`, что чаще всего бывает с попапами) его ширина равна нулю, а соответсвенно смысла что-то куда-то подставлять нет.

Единственное, что приходит в голову - это производить все расчеты после инициализации попапа.

Comment: Грубо говоря - это не будет работать:

<div id="modal" style="position: relative">
  <button id="button" style="position: absolute; left: 200px; top: 300px" />
</div>

А нужно вручную расчитать размеры окна и задать их?